# Membership limit on roles in snowflake being pushed by okta?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, okta

in trying to push a group's role membership to a role through okta in a relatively new snowflake account, we're getting the following error:

[image]

which reads "changes to the group push mapping for the group SNOWFLAKE_ANALYSTS could not take effect due to error: Error while creating user group SNOWFLAKE_ANALYSTS: . Errors reported by remote server: Requested number of membership exceeded the max limit 100 "

I cannot seem to find information suggesting there would be a limit to the group, but the text leads me to believe the error is coming from snowflake rather than okta.

Pushing roles to another account seems to do just fine; okta manages roles that have in excess of 100 members, like the one referenced above.

Is there some sort of membership limit that can apply to roles in snowflake? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Philipp, the limitation is on the Okta connector side. To overcome this you would need to create the Okta SCIM Native app and connect to Snowflake. That does not have the limitation for 100 users in a group.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is indeed a limit on SF side for a new role creation, when in Okta you have more than a 100 users in the group being pushed.